# How can I calculate a number in an input field with a value from a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, math

I'm trying to create a calculator-like program that takes the number you enter into the first input field and divides it by the number in the dropdown field below it. I'm trying to get a specific percentage of whatever number is entered in the first field.

However, I keep getting "NaN" when it runs. What should I change?

```js
const number = document.getElementById('number');
const percentageSelector = document.getElementById('percentageSelector');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');

//The mathematical stuff
submitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert(number * percentageSelector);
});
```

```html
<h2>Enter number here</h2>
  <input type="number" id="number">

<h2>Select a percentage to divide by</h2>
  <select id="percentageSelector">
    <option selected disabled>Pick one</option>
    <option>1%</option>
    <option>2%</option>
    <option>3%</option>
    <option>4%</option>
    <option>5%</option>
    <option>6%</option>
    <option>7%</option>
    <option>8%</option>
    <option>9%</option>
    <option>10%</option>
  </select>
  
  <button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Those are HTML elements, what you get from get***Element***ById. Read the documentation perhaps, like https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement to encounter `valueAsNumber` for the numerical input.

Comment: Don't use `type="submit"`... (only if you have a `<form>`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code ensures that the value of the inputs only get checked when the button is clicked. Values have also been added to each option and the value of the `percentageSelector` is checked using `percentageSelector.selectedOptions[0].value`.

I have also made a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Zeraora/szg4v69u/).

```js
const percentageSelector = document.getElementById('percentageSelector');
const submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');

//The mathematical stuff
submitButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  const number = document.getElementById('number').value;
  const percentage = percentageSelector.selectedOptions[0].value;

  alert(number * percentage);
});
```

```html
<h2>Enter number here</h2>
<input type="number" id="number">

<h2>Select a percentage to divide by</h2>
<select id="percentageSelector">
  <option selected disabled>Pick one</option>
  <option value="0.01">1%</option>
  <option value="0.02">2%</option>
  <option value="0.03">3%</option>
  <option value="0.04">4%</option>
  <option value="0.05">5%</option>
  <option value="0.06">6%</option>
  <option value="0.07">7%</option>
  <option value="0.08">8%</option>
  <option value="0.09">9%</option>
  <option value="0.1">10%</option>
</select>

<button type="submit" id="submitButton">Submit</button>
```

Comment: The math is coming out wrong. I entered 100 in the first field and then selected 8% and the value comes out to 12.5, which is incorrect. The value should be 8.

Comment: change  alert(number / (number * percentage)) to  alert(number * percentage)

Comment: @MohammedRaja Oops, I misinterpreted the question. I changed my answer now.

Comment: @MisterJojo Is `selectedOptions` better? By the way, I can do Maths, I just misinterpreted the question.

Answer (score 0):

This `const percentageSelector = document.getElementById('percentageSelector');` sets `percentageSelector` to the *element* not the *value* of the element. (Ditto "number").

Since the operands are set *outside* the click function, they will have the values as when the page loaded. You probably want to collect that info after the click, ie *inside* the function.

The value of a select element is the option that has been selected. The value is going to be the `value` attribute of the option. But none of the options has a `value`. Once you add values (as with `<option value=".01">`, it should be able to "do the math".

Answer (score 0):

so simple..  take care to use **numbers** and not string values

```js
const numberIn  = document.getElementById('number-in')
  ,   percent   = document.getElementById('percentage-Selector')
  ,   btCompute = document.getElementById('submit-Button')
  ;
btCompute.onclick=()=>
  {
  console.log('percent=', numberIn.valueAsNumber *Number(percent.value) /100)
  }
```

```html
<h2>Enter number here</h2>
<input type="number" id="number-in">

<h2>Select a percentage to divide by</h2>

<select id="percentage-Selector">
  <option selected disabled>Pick one</option>
  <option value="1">1%</option>
  <option value="2">2%</option>
  <option value="3">3%</option>
  <option value="4">4%</option>
  <option value="5">5%</option>
  <option value="6">6%</option>
  <option value="7">7%</option>
  <option value="8">8%</option>
  <option value="9">9%</option>
  <option value="10">10%</option>
</select>

<button id="submit-Button">Submit</button>
```